# Firebase custom authentication fails 400

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to use custom authentication to authenticate users to firebase. Created jwt token as they guided in documentation. But after send the token I'm getting this response

```
firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(response.body).catch(function (error) {
              // Handle Errors here.
              console.log(error)
            })

"error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "INVALID_CLAIMS"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "INVALID_CLAIMS"
 }
```

Console

> code: "auth/internal-error", message:
>   "{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"i…CLAIMS"}],"code":400,"message":"INVALID_CLAIMS"}}"

My jwt token is also in correct format.

Php code use to generate jwt token

```
public function authFirebase() {
        $now_seconds = time();
        $payload = [
          "iss" => $this->service_account_email,
          "sub" => $this->service_account_email,
          "aud" => "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/google.identity.identitytoolkit.v1.IdentityToolkit",
          "iat" => $now_seconds,
          "exp" => $now_seconds+(60*60),  // Maximum expiration time is one hour
          "uid" => \Auth::user()->id,
          "claims" => array()
        ];
        return JWT::encode($payload, $this->private_key, "RS256");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'claims' field in the custom token should contain a JSON object, instead of a JSON array.